# Update or create nuget packages on virtual machine

Tags: c#, nuget-package

I want to update my private nuget package(just related developers can see it) from an outside machine like google cloud or azure. When ı want to add a dll on a project which lots of develepers work on, ı have to inform my collegues and transfer my dll to their local machine. This is unpractical.With an outside machine when ı create or update a dll they can see that update on nuget package page.Please guide me how can ı achieve that?

[Here you can see nuget package settings on local machine and nuget server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally solve my problem. You can easily publish your project with azure. But still ı dont know how to publish on google cloud.